# Google People Api Implementation in android application

Tags: android

I am trying to use google people api but i am facing many difficulties. The json file generated from api console doesnt contain clientSecret. Where can i get it? So i am getting null authorization code. Can any one help me with this issue? Thanks in advance

```
   public void setUp() throws IOException {
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

            // Go to the Google Developers Console, open your application's
            // credentials page, and copy the client ID and client secret.
            // Then paste them into the following code.
            String clientId = "";
            String clientSecret = "";

            // Or your redirect URL for web based applications.
            String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
            String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly";

            // Step 1: Authorize -->
            String authorizationUrl = new GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl(clientId,
                    redirectUrl,
                    Arrays.asList(scope))
                    .build();

            // Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
            System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
            System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

            // Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
            String code = in.readLine();

            System.out.println(code);
            // End of Step 1 <--

            // Step 2: Exchange -->
            GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                    httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret, code, redirectUrl).execute();
            // End of Step 2 <--

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                    .build()
                    .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

            People peopleService = new People.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .build();

        }
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `clientSecrect` variable?

Comment: Did you read the comment above that variables,   // Go to the Google Developers Console, open your application's            // credentials page, and copy the client ID and client secret.            // Then paste them into the following code. Check it your google console.

Comment: sorry kalpana but i could not find clientSecrect there. I only got clientId.

Comment: What you placed on "String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";"?

Answer (score 1):

To get ClientID and ClientSecret, you should create Web Application ClientID and there are what you need.

Another thing to be noticed is that `response_type` from the url generated from `GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl` will be `token` which cause an error. I try changing `response_type` to `code` and it works.

The full url will look like

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=YOUR_ANDROID_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly`

Answer (score -1):

When you create the client ID, select the Application type as "other" then you can find the clientSecret. [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCZ95.png)

Comment: I think we have to redownload the json file.